# Junit Integration Test issue for testing create and exception functionality

Tags: java, testing, junit, integration-testing

I have been going through many articles on Integration Testing.As per my understanding we have to carry out test without using mocks. I need to test that if lobby is already present, it should throw the exception. I am creating lobby which in turn interacts with user service layer. Below integration test is failing with Null Pointer exception at userService.createUser(testUser) in setupLobby method.

What am I doing wrong with this Integration testing?

Integration Test Code -

```
public class LobbyServiceIntegrationTest {

LobbyService lobbyService;
UserService userService;

private User testUser;
private Lobby lobbyTest;
private Long lobbyId;
private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

@BeforeEach
public void setupLobby(){

    testUser = new User();
    testUser.setName("testName");
    testUser.setUsername("testUsername");

    testUser = userService.createUser(testUser);

    lobbyTest = new Lobby();
    lobbyTest.setName("testLobby");
    lobbyTest.setHostPlayerId(testUser.getId());

    lobbyId = lobbyService.createLobby(lobbyTest);


}

@Test
public void createdLobbyExist_Exception(){

    Lobby newLobby = new Lobby();
    newLobby.setName("testLobby");
    newLobby.setHostPlayerId(1L);

    assertThrows(LobbyException.class, ()->lobbyService.createLobby(newLobby));
}
```

}

Functionality which I want to test

```
    public Long createLobby(Lobby newLobby){

    checkIfLobbyExist(newLobby);
    newLobby.getPlayerIds().add(newLobby.getHostPlayerId());

    newLobby = lobbyRepository.save(newLobby);

    User user = userRepository.getOne(newLobby.getHostPlayerId());
    user.setLobbyId(newLobby.getId());
    userRepository.save(user);

    return newLobby.getId();

}
```

And create user

```
    public User createUser(User newUser) {

    checkIfUserExists(newUser);

    newUser.setToken(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    newUser.setStatus(UserStatus.OFFLINE);
    newUser.setCreationDate(new java.sql.Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));


    // saves the given entity but data is only persisted in the database once flush() is called
    newUser = userRepository.save(newUser);
    userRepository.flush();

    log.debug("Created Information for User: {}", newUser);
    return newUser;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Spring? If yes, you should configure for example H2 DB do perform such a task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your userService object nor lobbyService is not initialized at all that's why you are catching null pointer exception.

If you are using Spring framework then add to the top of the class @SpringBootTest annotation + @Autowired for userService and lobbyService.